# Iterable with two elements?

Tags: scala

We have `Option` which is an `Iterable` over 0 or 1 elements.

I would like to have such a thing with two elements. The best I have is

`Array(foo, bar).map{...}`, while what I would like is:

```
(foo, bar).map{...}
```

(such that Scala recognized there are two elements in the `Iterable`).

Does such a construction exist in the standard library?

EDIT: another solution is to create a `map` method:

```
def map(a:Foo) = {...}

val (mappedFoo, mappedBar) = (map(foo), map(bar))
```

Comment: `foo` and `bar` have the same type ?

Comment: yes foo and bar have the same type.

Comment: Do you mean, it should have 0 or 2 elements?

Comment: @Chirlo no exactly two elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is map on tuples of the same type, a simple version is:

```
implicit class DupleOps[T](t: (T,T)) {
  def map[B](f : T => B) = (f(t._1), f(t._2))
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
val t = (0,1)
val (x,y) = t.map( _ +1)  // x = 1, y = 2
```

There's no specific type in the scala standard library for mapping over exactly 2 elements.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you the following thing (I suppose foo and bar has the same type `T`):

```
(foo, bar)                         // -> Tuple2[T,T]
  .productIterator             // -> Iterator[Any]
  .map(_.asInstanceOf[T])    // -> Iterator[T]
  .map(x => // some works)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.

You could

1. Make one yourself.
2. Write an implicit conversion from 2-tuples to a `Seq` of the common supertype. But this won't yield 2-tuples from operations.

   ```
   object TupleOps {
       implicit def tupleToSeq[A <: C, B <: C](tuple: (A, B)): Seq[C] = Seq(tuple._1,tuple._2)
   }

   import TupleOps._

   (0, 1).map(_ + 1)
   ```
3. Use [HLists](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples) from shapeless. These provide operations on heterogenous lists, whereas you (probably?) have a homogeneous list, but it should work.